# Formartting SD Card - Corrupted FAT32 Filesystem

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, fat32, data-corruption

I have a corrupted SD Card whose filesystem is FAT32. I tried the following stuff but i am still able to see the contents in the SD card. I can neither add new files nor can i delete any files from the SD card. The contents seem to be locked within this SD card, similar to being locked in prison.

The things i have tried:

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc`

It took around 5-6 hours to finish this, but i could still see the contents.
dos

2. > `sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdc`

The verbose log said that dirty bit was identified and autocorrection of the corrupted bit has also taken place. But to no avail.

3. I tried clearing and formatting the partition using parted and gparted as well, but the result was unchanged.

Can someone explain this? Why did `dd` not work? 
Is there any other option other than buying a new SD Card?

Answer (score 2):

For what an SD card costs, the only effort warranted is attempting to recover data from the corrupted card, if there's anything on it worth that effort.  Otherwise, just buy a new card (you'll get several times the capacity for the same money you paid for the old one) and discard the old one.

Comment: yes i did, but i am not sure if this would not happen again on a FAT32 FS, if a filename is not right, for instance? I dont know. And i bought a new one, formatted it to ext4. Apparently, only rooted Android phones can work with ext4 formatted cards. By default, only FAT is supported.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been using FAT (FAT12, FAT16, and FAT32) for more than thirty years, and I've never seen a bad file name result in locking a volume.  That happens with SD cards (usually) because of a hardware fault in the Flash RAM or a glitch in the controller -- which is another reason it's better to replace than try to repair the FS.